# VirtualBox crashing when assembly “sti” is executed with while(1) when testing Operating System

Tags: c++, operating-system, virtualbox

I am trying to write an OS following the course :
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHh55M_Kq4OApWScZyPl5HhgsTJS9MZ6M.

After implementing the interrupt file i try to run the OS on VB but it crashed. I have checked my code with the course many times but just can't fine the error. can someone help me?

I have uploaded my code in GitHub https://github.com/ZirongCai/myos

Comment: I'd recommend using bochs debug version instead of Virtual Box since VB is not as good for debugging. Anyway, you can set the VBOX_GUI_DBG_ENABLED and VBOX_GUI_DBG_AUTO_SHOW environment variables to true on Windows to enable debug mode of VB. That way you will have an error message stating what happened and you can observe memory and everything using certain commands. You can find some commands here https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch12.html at 12.1.4 section. Find other commands typing 'help commands' in the debugging console (this will print all possible commands to the console).

Comment: If you are on Linux I'm not sure how to do that but you should switch to bochs anyway.